# What is the correct oil to use in an 80's era 6.9 Ford Diesel?

Tags: engine, ford, oil, diesel

What is the proper oil to use in an 80's Era 6.9 Ford Diesel?

Answer (score 1):

That's an International Harvester Diesel engine.

- SAE 15W-40 for normal conditions
- SAE 10W-30 if its cooler weather

And you're going to need 10 quarts.